# Python Seaborn rotate x axis labels but align labels to axis

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

I created a `Seaborn` `barplot` using the below code:

```
import seaborn as sns
barplot = sns.barplot(x='abc'
                      ,y='def'
                      ,data=df
                      ,ci=None
                      )
barplot.set_xticklabels(barplot.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45)    
barplot.figure
```

This code produced a `barplot` that looks like this:
[image]

Is there a way to rotate and align the x axis labels so the `barplot` looks something like this? So the end of the x axis labels are aligned to the x axis?

[image]

I am using Python 3.6 and seaborn 0.7.1

Comment: "The labels on the x axis lose their alignment with the x axis when the labels are long." That's not accurate. They're all aligned, they are just center-aligned and not right-aligned as in the second plot.

Comment: good point mwaskom. I just made an edit.